# heroku open =>relation "main_goal" does not exist LINE 1: ...y", "main_goal"."date", "main_goal"."status" FROM "main_goal

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models

When I run the Heroku open command , it returns an error

Everything works locally
Heroku run `manage.py migrate` doesn't help, `makemigrations` too, `manage.py migrate r run-syncdb` - also does not give anything

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it again.

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

If it doesn't fix the problem.

```
heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

If it's doesn't help I think you needs to share your logs maybe there is something you missed.